# Laptop is not charging (DELL Inspiron 13)

Tags: battery, power, dell-inspiron, charger

My laptop stopped charging all of a sudden. As a result, battery went down to %0 so I am not able to use it anymore.

What I have tried so far:
- Different power outlet
- 3 different brand-new chargers
- Different brand-new battery
- 2 different brand-new power jacks

What the problem would be?

Comment: Faulty circuity on the motherboard maybe ?

Comment: A bad power jack.

Comment: @Appleoddity already tried with different power jacks. I think it’s an issue on motherboard